# Как можно рандомно и плавно менять их местоположения согласно верстки?

Tags: html, jquery, css, css3, flexbox

У меня есть 12 блоков, подкиньте идею или даже код) Как можно рандомно и плавно менять их местоположения согласно верстки?

```css
.wrapper-box4 {
  width: 94.01%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #444;
}

.box-content1 div, 
.box-content2 div, 
.box-content3 div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #888;
  border: 1px dashed #fcfcfc;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 100px;
}

.box-content1, .box-content2, .box-content3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper-box4">
    <div class="box-content1">
      <div class="box-item1">1</div>
      <div class="box-item2">2</div>
      <div class="box-item3">3</div>
      <div class="box-item4">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content2">
      <div class="box-item5">5</div>
      <div class="box-item6">6</div>
      <div class="box-item7">7</div>
      <div class="box-item8">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content3">
      <div class="box-item9">9</div>
      <div class="box-item10">10</div>
      <div class="box-item11">11</div>
      <div class="box-item12">12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Опиши нормально вопрос, что именно ты хочешь? Людям гадать что и как ты хочешь ромдомно менять?

Comment: Что не понятного??? Рандомно менять местоположения блоков. То есть 12 поставить на место 2 или 5, потом 3 на место 4 или 8.

Comment: при клике...?  при скороле...? при изменении размера окна?  или когда путин пальцем щелкнет из кремля...  ???  или когда баба-дуся из воронежа душу богу отдаст?

Comment: При загрузке ст как елементарно)

Comment: А в каком месте при загрузке плавность?

Answer (score 0):

Коли пока никого нет, пускай будет так.

```js
function random(min, max, length) {    
    var numbers = []; 
    function _random(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    } 
    Array.apply(null, new Array(length)).reduce(function(previous) {
        var nextRandom;
        
        if(previous === min) {
            nextRandom = _random(min + 1, max);
        } else if(previous === max) {
            nextRandom = _random(min, max - 1);
        } else {
            if(_random(0, 1)) {
                nextRandom = _random(previous + 1, max);                
            } else {
                nextRandom = _random(min, previous - 1);            
            }
        } 
        numbers.push(nextRandom);
        return nextRandom;
    }, _random(min, max)); 
    return numbers;
};
  
         setTimeout(function() {
            $('li').eq(random(0, 18, 1)).addClass('li-js li-js2');
            $('li').eq(random(0, 18, 1)).addClass('li-js li-js2');
            $('li').eq(random(0, 18, 1)).addClass('li-js li-js2');
            $('li').eq(random(0, 18, 1)).addClass('li-js li-js2');
            $('li').eq(random(0, 18, 1)).addClass('li-js li-js2');
        }, 1000);
```

```css
/*autoprefixer used*/
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 10px
}
li {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font: 2em 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer
}
li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  color: blue;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.li-js {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-40%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
.li-js2 {
  order: -1;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgb(225,225,225);
  color: #225378;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.li-js2:before {
  content: "Now I'm first!";
  font-size: 0.6em
}
.li-js3 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо уже сам решил!))

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста )